# Change in datatype?

Tags: mysql, query, mysql-5, datatypes

I have a table on which rows are inserted on hourly basis. The row contains `id`, `installation`, `product_id` and `hit_allowed`. all of them were `mediumint` in the beginning. but few days back `id` reached it limit and I had to change the datatype to `bigint`.

But since then the script from which these rows are populated, it has stopped populating `product_id`. No changes in the script were made. Can anyone tell me if I will have to change the datatype for it too ?

Answer (score 3):

Please run the following query

```
SELECT product FROM mytable PROCEDURE ANALYSE();
```

[PROCEDURE ANALYSE()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/procedure-analyse.html) will tell to you the the min value, max value, and needed datatype.

If the product_id is mediumint and the highest value you have for product_id is 16777215, you've hit the max. Change to INT UNSIGNED not BIGINT.

```
ALTER TABLE mytable MODIFY COLUMN product_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL;
```

### UPDATE 2012-06-13 16:06 EDT

You could try importing the change differently.

```
CREATE TABLE pb_stat_rule_new LIKE pb_stat_rule;
ALTER TABLE pb_stat_rule_new MODIFY COLUMN product_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL;
INSERT INTO pb_stat_rule_new SELECT * FROM pb_stat_rule;
ALTER TABLE pb_stat_rule RENAME pb_stat_rule_old;
ALTER TABLE pb_stat_rule_new RENAME pb_stat_rule;
```

Try out the new file. If things still do not work, you can undo this:

```
ALTER TABLE pb_stat_rule RENAME pb_stat_rule_zap;
ALTER TABLE pb_stat_rule_old RENAME pb_stat_rule;
DROP TABLE pb_stat_rule_zap;
```

Comment: `"db_name.pb_stat_rule.product_id","0","16777215","1","8","3346985","1148373","26621.3943","45543.8722","MEDIUMINT(8) UNSIGNED"` This is the output of the query

Comment: but how do I know what value has it currently reached ?

Comment: It just suggested the datatype to be `MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED`. The max is 16777215. That means it cannot go further. You must change it to INT UNSIGNED.

Comment: the problem is `id` was a primary key and `product_id` is not, the maximum value thats in the column is 394874. So, how would it affect it ? There is another column named `installation` which is still populating the data ! Thanks for a quick reply

Comment: You cannot assign new values greater than 16777215. If you have values for product_id greater than 16777215 to assign, you must change it.

Comment: I know I cannot, but the maximum number i am assigning is 394874. Thats why i am confused !